# What is this U3 that came with my new USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, u3

I just purchased a new 16GB Sandisk Cruzer USB drive, it has drive that it mounts called U3. It is windows only and I downloaded the [Cruzer utilities for mac](http://mp3support.sandisk.com/downloads/cruzer-utility-mac.dmg) to remove them.

The thing is I have no idea what it is or what it is used for. Does anyone use U3 and find it beneficial ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the Wikipedia article on U3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3_(software)):

> U3 is a company producing a
> proprietary method of auto-launching
> applications from specially formatted
> USB flash drives. Flash drives
> adhering to the U3 specification are
> termed "U3 smart drives". U3 smart
> drives come preinstalled with the U3
> Launchpad, which looks similar to the
> Windows OS start menu and controls
> program installation. The method works
> with recent Microsoft Windows systems
> only. Applications which comply with
> U3 specifications are allowed to write
> files or registry information to the
> host computer, but they must remove
> this information when the flash drive
> is ejected. Customizations and
> settings are instead stored with the
> application on the flash drive.

I don't personally use the U3 software, but some less technologically-inclined people in my office appreciate having the file management built into their flash drive. You can also install portable applications onto the drive, but again, I find it easier to maintain my flash drives myself and use [http://portableapps.com/](https://portableapps.com/).

Comment: Oh I get it ... This is because Microsoft changed the behaviour of Windows 7 for flash drives to close a security hole.

Comment: Bruce: Windows has never started anything automatically from flash drives - so U3 drives from the beginning presented itself as both the actual drive and a virtual CD-ROM that contains the launcher. (Windows has no way to know if it's actually a CD-ROM or not.)

Comment: I've even got the u3 installer once to install a portableapps booter, instead of u3 `crap`.

Comment: Dykam: My friend likes replacing U3 with a keylogger, and leaving in certain places at school.

Comment: That... is also possible :p. Now get the my school back to allow stuff running from a usb-drive.

Comment: auto-starting applications from USBs is the best way to spread viruses

Answer (score 1):

I use U3 on a USB drive that I use for work to secure my employer's data.  It works fine in this total Windows environment however, I've always wondered how adequate the security is.

I remove it from my personal USB drives I use for home and travelling, because I don't always use a computer running Windows.

Comment: Can I ask how you removed it as I recently purchased a USB stick with U3 on it and I want it gone.

Comment: Gee, that would be a good question to post!

Answer is at http://u3.com/support/default.aspx#CQ3